# Expanding the "on-topic " page

Tags: discussion

The help center is supposed to contain -as it says:

> Detailed answers to any questions you might have

But I feel that the [on-topic page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) needs to be expanded a little bit more in order to contain all the answers a user might have. And since we are linking to this page very often, it is important that the user who reads it know exactly what this site is about.

I would suggest adding a list showing what topics are allowed here and what topics aren't (in summary) see for example [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) pages. The page should look like:

> ### Definition of the site
>
> If you have a question about:
>
> *"list goes here"*
>
> And not about:
>
> *"list goes here"*

If you have any suggestion please post it in an answer.

Comment: Thank you for finally migrating this ;-)

Comment: @caleb I'm sorry for being late, I was a little bit busy.